# why I cannot post my question?

Tags: discussion, posts

Today I try asking the question 'How to send a mail with two or three copies from Thunderbird?'; I have completed details 'I was used to click Enter after address for the copy; it resulted in showing further field for another address. Now, it does not work in my Thunderbird 91.5.0 in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.', added tags [18.04], [thunderbird] and [copy], clicked at 'Review your question' and got a message that the question is ready to post.

But when I click at 'Post your question' the page being displayed only returns to the same picture with the 'Post your question' pushbutton and the question does not appear among questions in my  user:165175 profile.

Comment: Could you please add a couple of screenshots in your question showing the problem? I'm not sure I understand it right now. Thanks!